# How to use interp2 in MATLAB

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab

I have some nodes in two dimensional, where $x,y$ are coordinates of them. Also, the value of $v$ is known in each node. Now it is necessary for me to have value of $v$ in some other nodes like $xq,yq$. To do this I used the following:

```
vq=interp2(x,y,v,xq,yq),
```

But there is an error:

> The grid vectors must contain unique points.

some of the $xq,yq$ are the same with some $x,y$. Is this the problem for such error? Also, I need a higher order interpolant, what is the best  method with reasonable cost for interpolation?

for example, in the simplest case

```
[x,y]=meshgrid(0:0.2:1,0:0.2:1);
 x=x(:);y=y(:);

 v=x.^2+y;

 xq=0.5;yq=0.5;
vq=interp2(x,y,v,xq,yq)
```

Comment: This question is impossible to answer without checking what you put into your $x$ et.c.

Comment: Give a use case where it can be expected to be reproducible and you are much more likely to get help.

Comment: I added a simple example with the same problem.

Comment: Great! Now you have something that someone with Matlab can try and reproduce on. Much larger chance that you will get a response.

Comment: If you skip the vectorization step "x=x(:);y=y(:);" it works for me in GNU Octave so you can try the same in Matlab if you want to. I get another error if I don't skip it, but that can be for some other reason.

Comment: Of course, but the problem is that in my case the points are not produced by meshgrid. in fact they are not uniformly distributed, they are randomly distributed.

Comment: For randomly distributore points you can't use interp2: you need a triangulation for your points (see delaunay and voronoy) and with that you can find the nearest point to the coordinates where you want the interpolate value. Using these points you can make an interpolation of any degree you may want (I would not go beyond degree 3). I'm sure a function exists in the PDE toolbox but I don't remember its name, anyway you need the triangulation also in that case

Comment: Sorry , get my mistake. interp2 is just for grided data, I can also use scatteredInterpolant(x,y,v);

Comment: Well they are on a grid since they originate from meshgrid, but Matlab apparently can't figure that out on it's own if you vectorize.